# Request ModelForm instance from Django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there any way to prepopulate the form fields with data from the model instance when I am generating the table?

Say I have a campaign model and I'm looping out the instance values and form fields in a table.

E.g. something like:

```
              {% for campaign in all_campaigns %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ campaign.get_status_display }}</td>
                    <td>{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ campaign.end_date }}</td>
                </tr>

                # --> have these form fields based on the campaign 
                #  instance that's being rendered above, so clicking an
                # edit button will edit this campaign instance ?
                <tr class='initially-hidden'>
                    <td>{{ campaign.id }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ form.name}} </td>
                    <td>{{ form.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.start_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.end_date }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [ModelFormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), and in particular using the `modelformset_factory` function. That will generate all the forms bundled up together for you, and you can then loop over them in your template using the [formset template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates).

You might find it easier/prettier to not bother printing the bare campaign details as per the top part of your code, but rather styling the form fields as uneditable text, and then enabling them when you click the edit button.